# Check if a range of cells has any number bigger or smaller than 0

Tags: excel, count, excel-formula

Is there a way to identify in column L if any of the cells between C and K contain a number greater or smaller than zero?

If yes it should return TRUE if not it should return FALSE. So in the example picture rows number 4 and 6 should return FALSE and rows number 1,2,5 should return TRUE.

[image: SO25803923 question example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In L2 you could use a formula like this:

```
=IF(OR(C2<>0;D2<>0;E2<>0;F2<>0;G2<>0;H2<>0;I2<>0;J2<>0;K2<>0);TRUE;FALSE)
```

and then just drag it down.

It will Return TRUE if there is a Value uneven 0 otherwise it will return FALSE.

Answer (score 5):

Please try in L2 and copied down to L6:

```
=COUNTIF(C2:K2,"<>"&0)<>0
```

This assumes there will only ever be numbers, not strings, in the range C2:K6. For L7 you might want:

```
=COUNTIF(L2:L6,"FALSE")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return False where all cells between column C and K contain '0' and return True for all other instances you could use:

```
=(CONCATENATE(C2,D2,E2,F2,G2,H2,I2,J2,K2)<>"000000000")
```

Or a shorter version:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(C2:K2,"<>0"),"True","False")
```

EDITED AGAIN - As per pnuts answer, this COUNTIF solution won't account 0 entered as a string, but the CONCATENATE one should

Answer (score -1):

If none of the cells from c2-k2 contain a value less or greater than zero, the sum of c2-k2 is 0 else the sum is less or greater than 0

> =IF(SUM(C2:K2)<>0;TRUE;FALSE)

Answer (score -1):

Use Array formula:

Enter the below formula in the cell L2 and press Ctrl+Shift+Enter

```
=AND(C2:K2>0)
```

You will get either TRUE or FALSE as answer